# Manually changing the color of the dots on a plotted graph

Tags: r, colors, figure

I currently have example code for a PLS-DA plot.

Say if I want to force a change of the colors not by the categorization, but by every three rows from the X data set. So for example, the first three data points (row1-row3) will be blue, then the next three in that X data will be green, and so forth. Is there a way to do that? I know we can use col = c("color1", "color2", etc) as a part of a command, but to my understanding, thats only for coloring the groups.

If there's a clever way to manually change the colors, that would also be super appreciated. I know there's a lot of data points in this example, so an example code just showing the first 3-6 points would be great, cause then I can learn through the rest. (from mixOmics package)

```
if(!require(mixOmics)) install.packages("mixOmics", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
suppressWarnings(library (mixOmics, verbose = FALSE))

data(iris)

# Prepare the data
X <- iris[, 1:4]  # Predictor variables
Y <- iris$Species  # Response variable

# Perform PLSDA
plsda <- plsda(X, Y, ncomp = 2)  # Set the number of components as 2

plotIndiv(plsda, ind.names = FALSE, legend=TRUE,
          comp=c(1,2), ellipse = FALSE, pch=16,
          title = "",
          star = TRUE, 
          cex = 1.5,
          point.lwd = 1,
          X.label = 'LV1', Y.label = 'LV2')
```

Comment: Which package is the function `plsda` from?

Comment: @Edward it is from mixOmics. Sorry! Edited it now to fix that part I forgot to add

Answer (score 0):

It turns out under the hood it's all `ggplot`, so you can create a grouping column, group by that, and it figures it all out for you:

```
X$grp <- rep(1:(nrow(X)/3), each = 3)

plotIndiv(plsda, ind.names = FALSE, legend=TRUE,
          comp=c(1,2), ellipse = FALSE, pch=16,
          title = "",
          star = TRUE, 
          cex = 1.5,
          point.lwd = 1,
          X.label = 'LV1', Y.label = 'LV2',
          group = X$grp)
```

[image: plot of points]